# Return string that is not a substring of other strings - is it possible in time less than O(n^2)?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, substring

You are given an array of strings. you have to return only those strings that are not sub strings of other strings in the array.
Input - `['abc','abcd','ab','def','efgd']`.
Output should be - `'abcd'` and `'efgd'`
I have come up with a solution in python that has time complexity O(n^2).
Is there a possible solution that gives a lesser time complexity?
My solution:

```
def sub(l,s):
  l1=l
  for i in range (len(l)):
        l1[i]=''.join(sorted(l1[i]))
  for i in l1:      
         if s in i:
              return True
  return False

def main(l):
      for i in range(len(l)):
            if sub(l[0:i-1]+l[i+1:],l[i])==False:
                  print l[i]


main(['abc','abcd','ab','def','efgd'])
```

Comment: Why isn't `'def'` in your expected output?

Comment: Posting your O(n^2) solution will likely make others more willing to help, since it shows an attempt first.

Comment: There might be an O(n) solution using a suffix tree, where n is the total number of characters among all the strings. But I am not sure.

Comment: Upvoted because it's a cool question, but I would urge you to post your solution, as others have mentioned here. Otherwise you're flirting with off-topic.

Comment: Obviously if the length of the elements is not bounded and `n` is the length *of the list* there is no possible bound for an algorithm since an element could be a list of arbitrary size.  If `n` is the sum of the lengths of the strings contained then there is an O(n) solution: build a [generalized suffixtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_suffix_tree) of the strings, then visit it and find all string endings that are leafs.

Comment: Is n the number of strings in the array or their total length?

Comment: Uhm, correction: the visit isn't that simple. You have to find the maximal leaves (that correspond to elements in the list) and then you make sure that their branch doesn't contain other maximal leaves. This can still be done with just one complex visit or doing two of them, but still O(n).

Answer (score 2):

Is memory an issue?  You could turn to the tried and true...TRIE!

Build a suffix tree!

Given your input `['abc','abcd','ab','def','efgd']`

We would have a tree of

```
              _
            / | \
           a  e  d
          /   |   \
         b*   f    e
        /     |     \
       c*     g      f*
      /       |
     d*       d*
```

Utilizing a DFS (Depth-First-Search) search of said tree you would locate the deepest leafs `abcd`, `efgd`, and `def`

Tree traversal is pretty straight forward and your time complexity is `O(n*m).` A much better improvement over the `O(n^2)` time you had previously.

With this approach it becomes simple to add new keys and still make it easy to find the unique keys.

Consider adding the key `deg`

your new tree would be approximately

```
              _
            / | \
           a  e  d
          /   |   \
         b*   f    e
        /     |   / \
       c*     g  g*   f*
      /       |
     d*       d*
```

With this new tree it is still a simple matter of performing a DFS search to obtain the unique keys that are not prefixes of others.

```
from typing import List


class Trie(object):
    class Leaf(object):
        def __init__(self, data, is_key):
            self.data = data
            self.is_key = is_key
            self.children = []

        def __str__(self):
            return "{}{}".format(self.data, "*" if self.is_key else "")

    def __init__(self, keys):
        self.root = Trie.Leaf('', False)
        for key in keys:
            self.add_key(key)

    def add_key(self, key):
        self._add(key, self.root.children)

    def has_suffix(self, suffix):
        leaf = self._find(suffix, self.root.children)

        if not leaf:
            return False

        # This is only a suffix if the returned leaf has children and itself is not a key
        if not leaf.is_key and leaf.children:
            return True

        return False

    def includes_key(self, key):
        leaf = self._find(key, self.root.children)

        if not leaf:
            return False

        return leaf.is_key

    def delete(self, key):
        """
        If the key is present as a unique key as in it does not have any children nor are any of its nodes comprised of
         we should delete all of the nodes up to the root
        If the key is a prefix of another long key in the trie, umark the leaf node
        if the key is present in the trie and contains no children but contains nodes that are keys we should delete all
         nodes up to the first encountered key
        :param key:
        :return:
        """

        if not key:
            raise KeyError

        self._delete(key, self.root.children, None)

    def _delete(self, key, children: List[Leaf], parents: (List[Leaf], None), key_idx=0, parent_key=False):
        if not parents:
            parents = [self.root]

        if key_idx >= len(key):
            return

        key_end = True if len(key) == key_idx + 1 else False
        suffix = key[key_idx]
        for leaf in children:
            if leaf.data == suffix:
                # we have encountered a leaf node that is a key we can't delete these
                # this means our key shares a common branch
                if leaf.is_key:
                    parent_key = True

                if key_end and leaf.children:
                    # We've encountered another key along the way
                    if parent_key:
                        leaf.is_key = False
                    else:
                        # delete all nodes recursively up to the top of the first node that has multiple children
                        self._clean_parents(key, key_idx, parents)
                elif key_end and not leaf.children:
                    # delete all nodes recursively up to the top of the first node that has multiple children
                    self._clean_parents(key, key_idx, parents)

                # Not at the key end so we need to keep traversing the tree down
                parents.append(leaf)
                self._delete(key, leaf.children, parents, key_idx + 1, key_end)

    def _clean_parents(self, key, key_idx, parents):
        stop = False
        while parents and not stop:
            p = parents.pop()

            # Need to stop processing a removal at a branch
            if len(p.children) > 1:
                stop = True

            # Locate our branch and kill its children
            for i in range(len(p.children)):
                if p.children[i].data == key[key_idx]:
                    p.children.pop(i)
                    break
            key_idx -= 1

    def _find(self, key, children: List[Leaf]):
        if not key:
            raise KeyError

        match = False
        if len(key) == 1:
            match = True

        suffix = key[0]
        for leaf in children:
            if leaf.data == suffix and not match:
                return self._find(key[1:], leaf.children)
            elif leaf.data == suffix and match:
                return leaf
        return None

    def _add(self, key, children: List[Leaf]):
        if not key:
            return

        is_key = False
        if len(key) == 1:
            is_key = True

        suffix = key[0]
        for leaf in children:
            if leaf.data == suffix:
                self._add(key[1:], leaf.children)
                break
        else:
            children.append(Trie.Leaf(suffix, is_key))
            self._add(key[1:], children[-1].children)

        return

    @staticmethod
    def _has_children(leaf):
        return bool(leaf.children)


def main():
    keys = ['ba', 'bag', 'a', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abd', 'xyz']
    trie = Trie(keys)
    print(trie.includes_key('ba'))  # True
    print(trie.includes_key('b'))  # False
    print(trie.includes_key('dog'))  # False
    print(trie.has_suffix('b'))  # True
    print(trie.has_suffix('ab'))  # True
    print(trie.has_suffix('abd'))   # False

    trie.delete('abd')  # Should only remove the d
    trie.delete('a')    # should unmark a as a key
    trie.delete('ba')   # should remove the ba trie
    trie.delete('xyz')  # Should remove the entire branch
    trie.delete('bag')  # should only remove the g

    print(trie)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Please note the above trie implementation does not have a DFS search implemented; however, provides you with some amazing legwork to get started.

Comment: I am fully aware that a trie is a heavy-weight data structure for searching so few keys; however, understanding the trie and its usefulness would allow one to perform this same search against the complete english dictionary in a fraction of the time given the use of simple arrays, sets alone.

Comment: Nice. OOC, do you know how this compares to Aho-Corasick? Looks like in general, they're fairly similar (both modifications of tries to make single pass searches for multiple strings possible), and I think Aho-Corasick does slightly more upfront work and may use slightly more memory to run faster on the scans, but I haven't looked at the details.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm not well versed enough to say exactly though the Aho-Corasick looks heavily optimized and now it's time to do some more learning.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) should allow you to get asymptotic run time of `O(n)`, at the expense of adding additional memory usage, and higher fixed multiplier on costs (ignored by big-O notation, but still meaningful). The complexity of the algorithm is the sum of several components, but none of them multiply, so it should be linear by all metrics (number of strings, length of strings, longest string, etc.).

Using [`pyahocorasick`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyahocorasick), you'd do an initial pass to make an automaton that can scan for all of the strings at once:

```
import ahocorasick

# This code assumes no duplicates in mystrings (which would make them mutually
# substrings). Easy to handle if needed, but simpler to avoid for demonstration

mystrings = ['abc','abcd','ab','def','efgd']

# Build Aho-Corasick automaton, involves O(n) (in combined length of mystrings) work
# Allows us to do single pass scans of a string for all strings in mystrings
# at once
aut = ahocorasick.Automaton()
for s in mystrings:
    # mapping string to itself means we're informed directly of which substring
    # we hit as we scan
    aut.add_word(s, s)
aut.make_automaton()

# Initially, assume all strings are non-substrings
nonsubstrings = set(mystrings)

# Scan each of mystrings for substrings from other mystrings
# This only involves a single pass of each s in mystrings thanks to Aho-Corasick,
# so it's only O(n+m) work, where n is again combined length of mystrings, and
# m is the number of substrings found during the search
for s in mystrings:
    for _, substr in aut.iter(s):
        if substr != s:
           nonsubstrings.discard(substr)

# A slightly more optimized version of the above loop, but admittedly less readable:
# from operator import itemgetter
# getsubstr = itemgetter(1)
# for s in mystrings:
#     nonsubstrings.difference_update(filter(s.__ne__, map(getsubstr, aut.iter(s))))

for nonsub in nonsubstrings:
    print(nonsub)
```

Note: Annoyingly, I'm on a machine without a compiler right now, so I can't install `pyahocorasick` to test this code, but I've used it before, and I believe this should work, modulo stupid typos.

Answer (score -1):

Pop the first element.  Go through each remaining element and see if the shorter string is a substring of the longer string.  Repeat.  That should be O(n log n)

EDIT: Rough draft of implementation

```
def not_substrings(l):
    mask = [True]*len(l)
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if not mask[i]:
            continue
        for j in range(i+1, len(l)):
            if len(l[i]) > len(l[j]):
                if l[j] in l[i]:
                    mask[j] = False
            elif l[j] == l[i]:
                mask[j] = False
                mask[i] = False
            else:
                if l[i] in l[j]:
                    mask[i] = False
        if mask[i]:
            print l[i]
```

I haven't run this code, but it should be roughly correct.  I don't know if there's a way of doing this without the mask, or what time complexity the `[True]*len(l)` statement has.  I haven't done any rigorous analysis, but this looks `n log n` to me, because each iteration only iterates over the remainer of the list, not the entire list.

Comment: Why would this run in O(n log n) time?

Comment: Repeat what? What do you mean by "shorter string" and "longer string"? How are they related to the one you pop? What does Repeat mean? pop the first element? The "shorter string"/"longer string"? Also: if you pop the elements one by one you *will* end up with O(n^2) complexity even without counting the time taken to compare the strings.

Comment: If the strings of the same length then check if they are the same string.  If they are different lengths, then only the shorter of the strings can be a substring of the larger string.

Comment: Let me whip up a rough implementation real quick, see if that would be easier to understand.

Comment: Each iteration covering the remainder of the list is still equivalent to `O(n^2)`; [the sum of numbers from 1 to n is `n(n+1) / 2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), which has a constant divisor, but that's irrelevant to big-O calculations, still `O(n^2)` removing constant factors. To make it `O(n log n)`, you'd need each iteration to iterate over half (or some fixed divisor) as many elements of the `list` as the last iteration did, not a subtractive reduction (e.g. one fewer elements).

Answer (score -1):

Use a `set` object to keep all the substrings. This is faster but use a lot of memory, if every string is short, you can try this.

```
import string
import random
from itertools import combinations

def get_substrings(w):
    return (w[s:e] for s, e in combinations(range(len(w)+1), 2))

def get_not_substrings(words):
    words = sorted(set(words), key=len, reverse=True)
    substrings = set()

    for w in words:
        if w not in substrings:
            yield w
            substrings.update(get_substrings(w))

words = ["".join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) 
    for _ in range(random.randint(1, 12))) for _ in range(10000)]
res = list(get_not_substrings(words))
```

Comment: Whether it's faster in practice is an open question, but in big-O notation, this is no improvement. Creating and storing every possible substring of a word is, as you can tell by the use of `itertools.combinations`, definitionally, an `O(n^2)` problem, solved once for every string (and it's `O(n^2)` on both memory and runtime, not to mention performing `O(n)` slicing operations for each combination of start/end indices, which makes it arguably `O(n^3)`); you have to assume any given string's length could be most of the total length, so that `O(n^2)` by itself ruins the whole thng.

Comment: It's not `O(n^3)`, because `n` is the length of the list, not the length of every string.

Comment: If the work involved in an algorithm grows much faster with the length of the longest string than it does with the number of strings, counting big-O in terms of number of strings is useless. You have to account for both in actual algorithmic analysis; if the algorithm performs terribly for either number of strings or length of strings, the most rapidly growing factor is what counts; big-O notation isn't about the best case scenario, it's about the worst case (occasionally, the "worst aside from nigh-impossible scenarios", e.g. we call `dict` lookups `O(1)` when they're conceivably `O(n)`).

Comment: Point is, if `n` is the length of the largest string, this is a `O(n^3)` algorithm, because `n` describes the number of combinations (`n^2`) and each slice caused by those combinations is `O(n)` itself. It's a single, consistent `n`.

Comment: if the length of strings are `k`, the length of list is `n`, then it's `O(k^3 * n)`. So if the strings are short, it's fast.

Comment: Right. But a solution that's got that sort of cost on both CPU and memory overhead is a terrible idea for a general purpose algorithm; you want something that will degrade gracefully, and with the worst case being cubic scaling, you've got an algorithm that will, if passed a `len` 1000 `str` as an argument, require >235 _MB_ of RAM; if passed a `len` 10,000 `str`, it needs >235 _GB_. Other solutions may have worse best cases, but their worst cases are less bad. That's why you look at big-O, so you don't go from "fast" to "heat death of universe slow" for the "wrong" (but realistic) input.